# Data label font family and size using mschart package

Tags: r, mschart, officer

I've been using the officer package for a few months now, but just getting into the mscharts package. I can't seem to find a way to adjust the font size and family of my charts' data labels.

Is there some function I'm not seeing that allows options within fp_text like there is with axis_title, legend_text, etc.?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yep, it does not exist. This will be implemented later

Comment: https://github.com/ardata-fr/mschart/issues/20

Comment: Ah ok, thanks David